# Enumerable and deferred execution of a method

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method: `int[] GetNumbers ();` which immediately returns array of numbers. However I can call this method only when class is initialized. I cannot initialize this class manually, it is initialized somewhere else by someone else.
I want to create `IEnumerable` which will call `GetNumbers()` when I will start iterating over that enumerable.

example:

```
    IEnumerable<int> numbers = new SomeKindOfWrapper (() => GetNumbers());
```

Now `GetNumbers()` will be called only when I try to access `numbers`.

How to achieve this? Is there something in NET framework that supports it?

I can pass delegate to my class which will call GetNumbers(), but I prefer IEnumerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create an iterator block that invokes the delegate and then yields the values in the sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SomeKindOfWrapper<T>(
    Func<IEnumerable<T>> generator)
{
    foreach(var item in generator())
        yield return item;
}
```

If you want to ensure that the delegate is never invoked more than once you can use `Lazy` instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SomeKindOfWrapper<T>(
    Lazy<IEnumerable<T>> sequence)
{
    foreach(var item in sequence.Value)
        yield return item;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, after edit u made it make sense :) But i think wrapper would be better, because I need to execute Func only once.

Comment: @zgnilec Then just wrap a `Lazy` instead of a `Func`.

Answer (score 2):

One kind of wrapper that you could use is [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Lazy<IEnumerable<int>> numbers = new Lazy<IEnumerable<int>>(() => GetNumbers());
```

You can use `numbers.Value`, or add a wrapper property for it:

```
IEnumerable<int> Numbers {
    get {
        return numbers.Value;
    }
}
```

The call of `GetNumbers()` is deferred until the first call of `numbers.Value`. After that the result is stored inside `Lazy<T>`, and returned to you on subsequent calls of `numbers.Value`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73347/discussion-on-answer-by-dasblinkenlight-enumerable-and-deferred-execution-of-a-m).